# Using EF 5 reverse engineer code first, why [Key] plus HasKey()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I'm using **EF reverse engineer** code First in order to get my POCOs and mapping tables.
I get folowing exception : EntityType 'MYPOCO' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
**I added [Key] attribute** on pk field and it works fine. But :

How come [Key] attribute has to be set on the poco PK attribute

```
[Key] // what's the reason for this redundancy with HasKey() in mapping class ?
public int ID_MYPOCO { get; set; }
```

whereas **it is allready mentioned in the mapping class** ...

```
public class MYPOCOMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MYPOCO>
{
    public MYPOCOMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID_MYPOCO);
    }
}
```

It is working and it is no big deal but wondering if there was any reason for this redundancy ?
Any how, very pleased with EF reverse engineering, my favorite way over the four ways to map DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the former is at `compile` time and the later is at `run time`.

Answer (score 2):

Although attributes like [Key] are used in DB generation, they are used for other things such as validation too, so need to be defined as well.